# Why is Backus naur form better than english?

Tags: compiler-construction, bnf

I was a quiz and I know one question that will be asked for sure but I have no idea how to answer it if anyone can help me please

Why is BNF better than English?

Comment: Generally, it isn't. In fact, for most purposes it is not even applicable, let alone good in any sense of the word. /s

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form

Comment: Yes but the questions says that it is better than english and I have no idea why

Answer (score 2):

English can sometimes be better, e.g. if you just want to buy something in shop :)

But in terms of computer science BNF is better than natural language, because it's formal, strict notation and using it you can more precisely describe grammar than doing it in natural language. In natural language meaning is not always as accurate as you need describing syntax.